# How to use ReadFrom.AppSettings in Serilog

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

I just discovered Serilog and I love it. However, I'm struggling to get it to read from app.config.

Code Configuration:

```
ILogger logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
    //.MinimumLevel.Verbose()
    .Enrich.WithProcessId()
    .Enrich.WithThreadId()
    .Enrich.WithMachineName()
    .Destructure.UsingAttributes()
    //.WriteTo.MSSqlServer(@"Server=EVDVWADBV1;Database=AppLog;Trusted_Connection=True;", "Logs")
    .CreateLogger();
Log.Logger = logger;
```

The commented out sections are the configuration values I want to read from a config file.

The config file contains:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Verbose"/>
    <add key="serilog:using" value="Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer"/>
    <add key="serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.connectionString" value="Server=EVDVWADBV1;Database=AppLog;Trusted_Connection=True;"/>
    <add key="serilog:writeto:MSSqlServer.tableName" value="Logs"/>
    <add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.pathFormat" value="C:\Logs\myapp-{Date}.txt" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.retainedFileCountLimit" value="10" />
</appSettings>
```

I'm using the following Serilog packages.

```
<package id="Serilog" version="1.5.14" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" version="3.0.41" targetFramework="net452" />
```

I also added this as the first line of my console app. I'm not seeing any errors on the console.

```
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Out = Console.Out;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt - Well, that was an embarrassing mistake to make. Thanks for the second set of eyes. Guess it's time for new glasses. Keep up the good work on Serilog. This is a fantastic tool.

Comment: Thank you Candi - glad to be able to help! --Nick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you may have a typo in the configuration:

```
serilog:writeto:MSSqlServer.tableName
```

Missing the dash:

```
serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.tableName
```